# Slim framework url as file path

Tags: php, rest, url, routes, url-routing

I'm new to using Slim and am trying to create a simple file hosting site. I'm trying to set my current directory via the url using `$app->get()`. Is there a way where I can have a url such as: `site.com/panel/documents/text/word/etc` where everything after `panel` is interpreted as the current path? I currently have this code:

```
$app->get('/panel/{path}', function ($request, $response) {
    $path = $request->getAttribute('path');

    return $path;
});
```

The issue is that I'm only able to return the `path` when only one path is set, I.E. `/panel/documents` returns `documents`. If I do something such as `/panel/documents/text` it will return a not found error. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the latest Slim v3, you can use placeholders to achieve your goal as per the documentation:
http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html#route-placeholders

Look for unlimited optional params

```
$app->get('/news[/{params:.*}]', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $params = explode('/', $request->getAttribute('params'));

    // $params is an array of all the optional segments
});
```

In your case it would be:

```
$app->get('/panel/{path:.*}', function ($request, $response) {
    $path = $request->getAttribute('path');

    return $path;
});
```

Comment: This is working but is throwing issues with my CSS files. Is there a workaround for this or should I just use a direct path to the URL of the file?

Comment: I would look at your .htaccess file or webserver configuration. You should ensure you only redirect to PHP if a local file cannot be found. The information on http://www.slimframework.com/docs/start/web-servers.html is how it should be setup. Failing that you might need to address you paths to your CSS files.

Comment: My `.htaccess` is using the recommended configuration for Apache. Is there something else I need to add?

Comment: How strange, it should load your css file if it can be found and only redirect when it doesn't exist if you are using the .htaccess described. You can always add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(css|assets|images)/(.*)$` to the .htaccess, changing css|assets|images etc to your actual asset directories. This would be above the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` line